# How do I send signal from one thread to main thream QML?

Tags: qt

Faced the problem of sending a signal from one thread to the main thread.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    
    ThreadsManagement management;
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("eventHandler", management.getEventHandler());
    
    engine.addImportPath("qrc:/");
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

In the main thread I create an object that is responsible for other threads with objects.
Further, from it I get a pointer to the object (EventHandler) that I have through signals and slots communicates with the GUI. From it(EventHandler) I send data to the QML and I need to respond to certain signals in it.

```
    Connections
    {
        target: eventHandler
        function onSignalAlertUserExists()
        {
            console.log("user exists");
        }
    }
```

So, I need to respond to the signalAlertUserExists() signal already in the main thread. But I get an error
QQmlEngine: Illegal attempt to connect to EventHandler(0x55920259e4e0) that is in a different thread than the QML engine QQmlApplicationEngine(0x7ffe13052540.

I understand that the main thread cannot receive a signal from another thread, but I do not understand how to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance for those who respond
Thx.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Signals can be sent to other threads. Read [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) about different signal connection types. If a signal is connected to a slot on a different thread, it should default to a queued connection.

Comment: Then explain to me where this error is coming from? It is written that different threads. example with this situation https://www.dropbox.com/s/sv6yi6mgq4ffx6s/untitled1.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: I'm not going to download some random file from your dropbox. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: This is code from my test proj with error. https://collabedit.com/x4v36